# Test file is not taking in consideration the code in main.py

Tags: python, robotframework

I’ve this code in the main.py file that returns the name of the youngest and oldest name from a dictionary:

```
def youngest_and_oldest_names(persons):
    return min(persons, key=persons.get) + " " + max(persons, key=persons.get)

print(youngest_and_oldest_names({
  "John X": 12,
  "Kate Y": 10,
  "Boris Z": 16,
  "Mike w": 11,
}))
```

Im learning about robot framework, I created a `test.robot` file with this structure below, to test the output of the youngest_and_older_names function:

```
  *** Settings ***
   
  *** Variables ***
  ${Result}  Kate Y Boris Z
   
  *** Test Cases ***
  OldestNamesTest
   
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${Result} Kate Y Boris Z
```

Executing the test case as it is with `robot test1.robot` it shows:

```
Test1                                                             | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
```

However it seems that is not taking in consideration the code in the main.py file. The goal of the test is to verify that the output of the `youngest_and_oldest_names` function is correct. Do you know what is necessary for the link?

Like this:

```
  *** Settings ***
  Library  ../main.py
  *** Variables ***
  ${Result}  Kate Y Boris Z
   
  *** Test Cases ***
  OldestNamesTest
     ${result}=  evaluate  main.youngest_and_oldest_names()  persons


    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${Result} Kate Y Boris Z
```

Shows the error:

```
Evaluating expression 'main.youngest_and_oldest_names()' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'persons'
```

Comment: You need to import your library in settings with `Library    main.py` or similar. Robot Framework documentation has a good section about extending Robot Framework with examples: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extending-robot-framework

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question and it shows now: Evaluating expression 'main.youngest_and_oldest_names()' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'persons'. Do you know why?

Comment: You are trying to combine two methods of executing functions. Proper way to run is simpler: Python functions become keyword after you import them. Keyword `youngest_and_oldest_names` requires a dictionary so first you need to create it with `${persons}=    Create Dictionary    John X    12    Kate Y   10    Boris Z    16    Mike W   11`. You can then pass it to your function `${result}=  main.youngest_and_oldest_names   ${persons}`